# PHP MVC can't access controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller, controller

I have this simple PHP code where I have created a new model with a celebrity name, a controller that accesses the celebrity name from the model, and a view to display the name. For some reason using the path below I can't display the name accessing the controller. I can't find out what I am missing or doing wrong.
Thanks for the help!

> http://localhost/ci/Starcontroller/guess

**Controller->**

```
    <?php
class Starcontroller extends CI_Controller{
    function __construct() {parent::__construct();}
    function guess()
    {
        $this->load->model('starmodel');
        $newstarr = $this->starmodel->lookup();
        $this->load->view('starview',$newstarr);
    }
}   
?>
```

Model->

```
<?php
class starmodel extends CI_Model{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    public function lookup(){

    $celebrity = "Anna";
    return $celebrity;
    }
}
?>
```

View ->

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

    <?php
        echo $newstarr;
    ?>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: name the intial of  class in captial like `class Hero { }` and file name also

Comment: @AnmolRaghuvanshiVersion1.0 I am aware of this and names of classes start with a capital letter same as the name of the file name. Modified the class name for controller still no results. 
Error: **The requested URL /ci/Starcontroller was not found on this server**
This works: **http://localhost/ci/**

Comment: see your model class starmodel small s

Comment: @AnmolRaghuvanshiVersion1.0 yes modified that. still no results.

Comment: well can you access it with `index.php` like `http://localhost/ci/index.php/Starcontroller/guess`

Comment: @AnmolRaghuvanshiVersion1.0 Yes I can. I just get errors now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93264/discussion-between-anmol-raghuvanshi-version-1-0-and-otonel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First initial alphabet of Class name and File name of controller and model are in capital letter's check your model class name

Then in controller change to this

```
<?php

class Starcontroller extends CI_Controller {

   function __construct() {
      parent::__construct();
      // Would load model in here and other helpers and libraries.
      // So can access through all functions on controller.
      // $this->load->model('starmodel');
   }

   function guess() {
      $this->load->model('starmodel');
      $newstarr['data'] = $this->starmodel->lookup();
      $this->load->view('starview',$newstarr);
   }

}
```

**In view**

```
<?php echo $data ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

From controller, you would like to pass an associative array of data to the view.
So change this part:

```
$newstarr = $this->starmodel->lookup();
$this->load->view('starview',$newstarr);
```

To this:

```
$data['newstarr'] = $this->starmodel->lookup();
$this->load->view('starview',$data);
```

Rest of your code may stay the same.